# Cron Jobs vs Security Rules

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, cron, firebase-security

In terms of security and speed, in order to have expiring data in a firebase data, would it be more secure to use a cron job to delete data after it has expired or use security rules in order to allow certain items to be read if they have been posted under a certain time period? The security rules I have are:

```
 "rules": {
     "posts": {
       "$postID": {
        ".read": "data.child('timestamp').val() > (now - 86400)",
```

Furthermore, the user would only retrieve posts where the time stamp is less than than a day old. However, the problem with this is that the posts are displayed in a table view through a list. If a post expires just while the user is in the app, it will only disappear when the app queries for data again. Would it be better to use a cron job to add a timer after each post is added, deleting the child entry when the post is older than 24 hours in terms of security and speed, while feasibly having a timer for each and every child in the firebase database?

Answer (score 0):

A "cron" job isn't a timer.  It's the periodic execution of some code (for example: hourly, weekly, daily).  You can't configure a cron-style scheduler on a per-item basis.  It will simply execute on the single schedule that you specify.

If you absolutely must lock down data after some time that's defined per-item, security rules gets you there better.  However, if your rules allowed the user to list all the items at a location, that means you had to give them unconditional read access to the entire node with that list.  Once you've done that, you can't deny access to children at that location.  The way security rules work is that once someone has read access at a location, they can read all children regardless of the child rules.

Comment: What would be the best way to implement posts that expire after a certain time period, such as Snapchat Stories? Would a cron job that runs every second be feasible? Once a post expires, the user should no longer have access to it, and security rules would allow them to view it after the rules change according to you @Doug

Comment: You could certainly try that.

Comment: if I use security rules, you said that when a person has access to a location they can read it regardless of the rules. This is not the desired result, as the user should not be able to see the post even if they once had access to it. Would there be an alternative to a cron Job for each post, or a possibility through just cloud functions to remove posts that are older than a certain time?

Comment: There are currently no scheduling mechanisms provided by Firebase.

Comment: I think the best solution is to run a cron job every minute, add security rules that don't allow a user to read posts where the time is greater than an hour, AND on the user end query only for data where the time is less than a day old. That way, even if a user has an expired post they'll only have the post for a minute before the cron job deletes it, if a user logs in, they will not be able to get the expired post as the query will not allow them to get it, and the database security rule can be an extra layer of security.However,  almost 87,000 functions will be called just by that.